# Does there exist a scalene triangle with integer side-lengths and an integer height.

Tags: geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry

I recently got fascinated by this question:

> Does there exist a scalene triangle $\triangle ABC$ where $AB, AC, $ and $BC$ are integers and $\triangle ABC$ has an integer height?

There is some ambiguity around where the 'height' is but I assume that it is perpendicular from any of the sides.

Cheers!

***EDIT:*** Right-angled triangles are not permitted, I think the question wants a generalisation, if it exists...

Comment: Unless you specifically state that right triangles are not counted, there are obvious solutions

Comment: Don’t most Pythagorean triangles satisfy these conditions?

Comment: @MathLover I think right angles aren't counted... I forgot to add that bit in, I will do now!

Comment: Join two different right triangles: $4\cdot (5,4,3)$ and $(12,5,13)$ give $(20,21,13)$ with an integer height $12$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice example is

- a $13,14,15$ triangle, with height $12$ perpendicular to the $14$ side

and if you multiply these numbers by $195$ you get the more impressive example with all three heights integers:

- a $2535, 2730,2925$ triangle with respective heights $2520,2340,2184$